# Remove rows based on reverse condition in columns

Tags: r, filter

I have a large dataset for which this needs to be done but I will describe the problem for a smaller one.

| Var1 | Var2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| A | C |
| A | D |
| B | A |
| E | F |
| G | H |

I want to keep only one of the rows with values "A-B" and drop the row with the reverse "B-A". All the other rows should also remain.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand correctly

```r
df <- df <- data.frame(
  Var1 = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'E', 'G'),
  Var2 = c('B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'F', 'H')
)

fltr <- !duplicated(apply(df, 1, function(x) paste0(sort(x), collapse = "")))

df[fltr, ]
#>   Var1 Var2
#> 1    A    B
#> 2    A    C
#> 3    A    D
#> 5    E    F
#> 6    G    H
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
df[!(df$Var1 == 'B' & df$Var1 == 'A'), ]
```

With dplyr:

```
dplyr::filter(df, !(Var1 == 'B' & Var1 == 'A'))
```

Reproducible input data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Var1 = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'E', 'G'),
  Var2 = c('B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'F', 'H')
)
```

Comment: Yes it can be done like that for the small number of observations but my actual dataset is very large so I can't hard-code it this way.

Comment: So you have more columns? What is the logic, they can't break alphabetic order?

Comment: It does what you asked for, and the proposed solution would work on any dataset regardless of its size. If that's not the solution to your problem, please state more clearly what you need to accomplish, post a subset of your data using `dput`, and show an example of the desired results.